# A random "<" opening angle bracket displaying on my website

Tags: php, html

I've searched the hell out of this issue, but due to the fact that most websites remove all "<" for obvious reasons, it has not been an easy thing to find and a search for the term involving angle brackets just gives me 12000 pages of html tuts. I've also ran a search on here with no joy. Basically I've got this random "<" angle bracket displaying on my website, you can see it here http://sunnahspace.com and I've got no idea why it's there. I'm assuming it's something really simple like a space between the bracket and content, or something like that but I've combed through the content line by line with no discrepancies. Perhaps I just need to get away from the screen for a few hours to get my eyes aligned but I'm just not seeing it. Can anyone just give me a quick list to figure out why it'd do this, I'm trying to get used to debugging myself, so I'd rather find the error myself if possible, I just want to know what would cause this error. Thanks :)

Comment: I'd suggest you just start putting debugging echo's until you find the source file

Comment: Validate your HTML. There are nesting errors -> http://validator.w3.org

Comment: [validate, validate, validate](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fsunnahspace.com%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0) and don't use [layout tables](http://www.hotdesign.com/seybold/)

Comment: Use the w3.org validator: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fsunnahspace.com%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0&ss=1

Comment: both your html and css are littered with errors, it could be anywhere. it is most likely some error because of a unclosed attribute

Comment: Without knowing your code the only thing I can see from inspecting the element on the site is that there is a `<td>` element with a `<style></style>` and this < between quotes. Perhaps it is some kind of a truncated tag - perhaps another style or script tag? Try and look in your code for where the preceding style is being spat out. At least it will tell you where to look next. Oh and one piece of advice - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/83073/why-not-use-tables-for-layout-in-html

Comment: I just started this page this morning, I should of validated before asking, but I will definitely validate soon. Can anyone offer some resources where I can learn to use divs and css to do what I am attempting to do via tables, preferably in the form of video tutorials. From the tutorials and so on that I've learned from tables were used because they are much easier to just throw up there, though the same tutorials warned about the general distaste of their misuse. Resources would be great, I'd have to ask less questions on here :)

Answer (score 6):

The extra `<` is inside the table, but outside a `td` element, so the browser moves it outside the table.

On line 87 you have:

```
<<td width="638" ...
```

Note: I see that you have `style` elements inside the body. This is non-standard, so you should move them into the `head` element if possible.

Comment: there are style elements inside the linked .css. this non-standard tag is trivial

Comment: Yeah, I actually separated the header, body and footer into different files, and used php require_once to insert them to the index however it keeps reverting to the standard styles if I take the styles out of their original files and insert them into the index. I originally created a main.css file if you look at the top I link the index to it, however it doesn't apply them for some reason. I'm actually going to school for web design and development, but I'm self taught so far at the "developing" part so I still have a lot to learn.

Answer (score 3):

Think this is your problem

```
 <tr> 
    <<td width="638" height="301" background="../img/container_btm.jpg" style="background-repeat:no-repeat; vertical-align:top"></td> 
    <td style="padding-top:7px; padding-left:7px"><span style="padding-bottom:7px; padding-right:7px">Test</span></td> 
  </tr>
```

After the first tag you have a spare < floating around :-)

Comment: +1, yes, it's there at line 87

Comment: Awesome, thanks... I guess the answer is that I need to step away from the computer for a few minutes :P thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is an extra '<':

```
<<td width="638" height="301" background="../img/container_btm.jpg" style="background-repeat:no-repeat; vertical-align:top"></td>
```

Also, this `table` opening tag is botched:

```
<table width="100%" border="0" style="margin:0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" "background-repeat:repeat-x" background="../img/footer_bg.jpg">
```

For future reference, in situations like this one it's helpful to use W3C's validate-by-input service: http://validator.w3.org/#validate-by-input